# How to test Google Analytics track event for Mobile Applications?

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have implemented Google Analytics in my iPhone Application. And I can able to see the pageviews in Google Analytics Dashboard. But I don't know where(how) to check track event in Google Analytics Dashboard.

Comment: btw: new the design is like hell!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In left side menu there is one option called events you can see there

[image]

I think it will help ...